# Sending JSON in body of an email

Tags: data, json, email, integration, development-approach

Basically, in our scenario, data has to be sent from a WordPress form to Dynamics 365. My current approach is putting it into an email body in JSON format, that is then extracted and further processed by Power Automate flow. ("Power Automate" is Microsoft's "low code" / "no code" product)

Everything is working fine but there is a disagreement in the team if this is a viable approach or not.

I know Dynamics offers an API, and I could use that also. But my idea for choosing an email over API is to adopt 'low code no code' approach wherever possible. On the other hand, I think the API code would require higher development skills every time to change or fix something.

So are there any caveats we should be aware of, specifically regardimg maintenance and/or robustness?

Comment: If it is “working fine,” how is it not viable? It would be more standard to have a server with an API endpoint that accepts JSON, but this doesn’t make the current approach wrong.

Comment: What level of data integrity/verification do you require?  IMHO it is not the best idea in most cases but it may be reasonable in some cases.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. You don't avoid approach "Foo" because some narrow-minded colleague thinks "Foo" is *"generally a bad development approach"*, especially when those colleagues cannot tell you why. You avoid an approach when there is a simpler and/or more reliable alternative is available. To find out about the latter, you have to ask experts of the specific product you are using. So why don't you ask in a Microsoft Dynamics Forum what possibilities that system offers, and then compare them to your "email" approach?

Comment: @DocBrown I know Dynamics offer API and I can use that also. But my idea for choosing an email over API is to adopt 'low code no code' approach wherever possible. On the other hand, API code would require development skills every time to change or fix something.

Comment: @KhadimAli: and adding a JSON file from WordPress - programmatically, I assume -, and extracting the file by the receiver does not require development skills, or fewer than using an API? Maybe that's true, I don't know.
But If that's the case, you should edit the question and add this information, currently it gives the impression you have an XY problem. This also gives you the opportunity to remove this nonsense about "generally bad development approach" out of it.

Comment: @DocBrown Thanks. Updated the question. For adding JSON I created and provided the JSON to the WordPress guy, he pasted that into an email body manually and then replaced the placeholders with WordPress form tags. Extracting the JSON is done using Power Automate (Microsoft's low code no code product).

Comment: @KhadimAli: I still think this question has some potential for becoming a good one. However, there there is still information hidden doiwn here in the comments which should be part of the question (specificially what "Power Automate" is and what it has to do with "low code"). And, honestly, asking for "generally good or bad development approaches" looks like a relgious believe to me, not like a professional , pragmatic point of view. Let me try to fix this.

Comment: ... ok, I took the freedom to edit the question and asked a more specific question about criteria like maintenance and robustness, since I guess that is what you really wanted to know. Please double check if I got your intentions right.

Comment: @DocBrown sending data is an objective, not JSON itself. I have updated this in the question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a slightly *creative* architecture, but generally fine. Some caveats:

- Email is notoriously unreliable: emails may arrive delayed, out of order, or not at all.
- Emails are not necessarily encrypted in transit, though in practice it's possible to ensure that hops between known servers will use an encrypted connection.
- The content of plaintext emails is typically line-wrapped, which could damage the JSON contents. Avoid this by setting an appropriate MIME type for the content or by sending the JSON as an attachment.

Comment: The line wrapping is a problem since JSON required that a string is contained in one line. Would have been better to have a rule like in C where multiple strings separated by white space count as a single string. So an attachment it is, and you can send encrypted JSON as an attachment even if the email isn’t encrypted.

Comment: @gnasher729 Try to send line longer than 2KiB in email body [1KiB on many SMTP servers]

Answer (score 3):

JSON in the email body is problematic. Mostly because it’s between hard and impossible to guarantee that an email body isn’t modified by anyone. JSON in an attachment is just fine, especially if you encrypt it.